# Selenium Java automation runs fast in some machine and slow in some machine

Tags: java, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am newbie in automation world. Recently, I created some automation script for my work. Its working good. The problems that I am facing are:

1. This script work in normal speed in my machine but if i use the same script in my friend's computer, its super super fast. So fast that its braking the automation steps.
2. This automation works good on my machine with Firefox driver but if i try to use Chrome driver, again its super super fast that it breaks the automation step.

Is there any solution for this? Why automation acts differently in different machine? Is there a way to configure the speed.,..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes kiran you can add explict wait. Please find the code below :

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20 );// Explicit wait()
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("xyz")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be using different driver exes with different machine.. I have observed pathetic performance while using IEdriver for 64 bit. Try using same webdriver exes on both the machines. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Dear if it work fast its good but if its getting failed because of not fining the particular field you are locating, in that case you can use the Implicit or Explicit wait so that the your driver should wait until it doesn't found particular item you are locating.

You can also use Thread.sleep(5000) but that is not a good practice.

Comment: If possible, you don't want to have to slow down every statement.  If there are problem statements (caused by slow js load time) then you can place waits there.  However, if every the majority of your statements are breaking, you can override the findElement() method to add an implicit wait.